# How to join on multiple column with a groupby in Django/Postgres

Tags: django, postgresql

I have the following tables that I need to join on date and currency:

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateField()
    amount = models.FloatField()
    currency = models.ForeignKey(Currency, on_delete=models.PROTECT)


class ExchangeRate(models):
    currency = models.ForeignKey(Currency, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    rate = models.FloatField()
    date = models.DateField()
```

I need to join on both the date and currency columns, multiply the rate and the amount to give me the 'converted_amount'. I then need to group all the transactions by calendar month and sum up the 'converted_amount'.

Is this possible using the Django ORM or would I need to use SQL directly? If so, how do I go about doing this in Postgres?

Comment: can you add models here???

Comment: What do you mean with "get the total value in the different currency" ? total value of what : one transcation, several transactions ?

Comment: @MohamedBeltagy I've added more details

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the `Dates` in the `"Exchange rates"` table are independent from the `dates` in the `Transactions` table, so that for each Transaction, the corresponding `"Exchange rates".Date` is the latest date which is less or equal than the `Transactions.Date`, you can try this in Postgres :

In Postgres :

```
SELECT t.Currency
     , date_trunc('month', t.Date) AS period_of_time
     , sum(t.amount * er.Rate) AS sum_by_currency_by_period_of_time
  FROM Transactions AS t
 CROSS JOIN LATERAL
     ( SELECT DISTINCT ON (er.Currency) er.Rate
         FROM "Exchange rates" AS er
        WHERE er.Currency = t.Currency
          AND er.Date <= t.Date
        ORDER BY er.Date DESC
     ) AS er
 GROUP BY t.Currency, date_trunc('month', t.Date)
```

Comment: Wow, thanks Edouard. I assume something like this won't be possible in the Django ORM?

Comment: @Kritz, sorry I have no competency in Django ... I hope you will find a way to insert sql code, or to call a postgres function from Django.

Comment: No problem - thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `Currency` model has a symbol column (change to your needs) you can achieve this with the following Django statements:

```
from your.models import Transaction, ExchangeRate
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractMonth
from django.db.models import Sum, F, Subquery, OuterRef

rates = ExchangeRate.objects.filter(
    currency=OuterRef("currency"), date__lt=OuterRef("date")
).order_by("-date")

Transaction.objects.annotate(
    month=ExtractMonth("date"),
    rate=Subquery(rates.values("rate")[:1]),
    conversion=F("amount") * F("rate"),
).values("currency__symbol", "month").annotate(sum=Sum("conversion")).order_by(
    "currency", "month"
)
```

This will result in a list like:

```
{'currency__symbol': '$', 'month': 2, 'sum': 105.0},...
```

The subquery statement will annotate the last found exchange rate comparing the dates. Make sure that each transaction has an exchange rate (exchange rate date prior transaction date).